# How to reload the contents of a PrimeNG Dialog

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dialog

I am using Angular PrimeNG and I have the following scenario

```
<button (click)="display = !display">Open</button>
<p-dialog [(visible)]="display">
    <custom-component [uid]="userId"></custom-component>
</p-dialog>
```

Problem here is whenever I try to open the p-dialog, the custom component is not called again, how do I make sure the component is loaded again to make sure the modal has latest data every time its opened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to add an `*ngIf` statement to the component. So whenever the  flag is false the component is destroyed. Opening the dialog again should create the component again.

Comment: i also thought the same, tried it too, still doesn't work, the modal opens with old data

Comment: You can use the flag as an input and reload the data in the component.
HTML:
`<custom-component [isVisible]="display"></custom-component>`

TS custom-component:
`@Input()
set isVisible(visible: boolean) { // Reload data when visible is true }`

edit: formatting

Comment: hmm makes sense, ill try this tomorrow (I'm off work now) and return back